# Why is there mutual inductance in the 5 H coil if no time varying current flows in the 4 H coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image: This is the circuit with 5H and 4H coil.]

In the answer given to me, when mesh analysis is applied to the mesh 1(the one with 5H coil), they show this,
[image]

This does not make sense to me as there is no current(I2) in mesh 2 because there is no AC voltage source in mesh 2 for the 4H coil to induce EMF in 5H coil, so my question is how is 10(I2)j part coming in this equation. I hope someone can clarify.

Comment: You should clarify what the problem statement was, just giving us part of the solution doesn't help to understand why that solution was given.

Answer (score 0):

If the voltages and currents are expressed as phasors, as they are here, they represent AC voltages and currents. So there is, in fact, time varying current flowing through the solenoids.

Answer (score 0):

*. . . . there is no current(I2) in mesh 2 because there is no AC voltage source in mesh 2 for the 4H coil to induce EMF in 5H coil . . . .*

The symbol used in the diagram is often the same for an alternating voltage as well as as a direct voltage and the voltage quoted is then the peak or rms value.